# How to make sticky footer

Tags: css

```
<body>
<div id="containers" >     
<div id="header">
<table> <tr>
<td><div id="logo"></div></td><td><div id="band-logo"> 
</div></td><td><div id="facebook"></div></td><td>
</td></tr> 
<div id="amenu">

<ul id="mainMenu"><li id="first"></li><li></li><li id="last"></li></ul></div> 

<div id="clearheader"></div>

</div>

<div id="container">



<div id="subMainBox"></div>
<div id="mainBox">
<div id="contents">
</div></div>
</div>  
<div id="footer_show"> <div id="fd">
<div id=copy_right><br /><strong></strong></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

(CSS CODE UPDATED)
    #containers{
    width:1000px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-20px;
    }

```
#container{
position:relative;
top:-247px;}

#header{
width:1000px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
} 
#contents{
position:relative;
top:-60px;
left:30px;
}

#mainBox{
height:500px;
float:right;
width:650px;
margin:0 150px 0 150px;
}

#mainBox2{
float:right;
width:650px;
margin:0 120px 0 150px;
}
```

The code as above, can anyone help to make this code to sticky footer? I have tried many methods. Thanks.(CSS CODE UPDATED)

Comment: What do you mean by relative footer? Where's your CSS?

Comment: What is a Relative Footer? Do you mean Sticky Footer?

Comment: Yes, i need a sticky footer

Comment: I think you should clean your html first and indent it right. You have a table tag that is not closed, you have many useless tags (div, li, etc), the indentation is horrifying and it's really hard to see something in there.